# What is really stored in net.params[layer].diff in Caffe?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I know that `net.params[layer].diff` should be the derivatives of loss function to weights, i.e. `net.params[layer].data`, however, I get confused with the following example: it is a 3-layer (ip1, ip2, ip3) fully-connected net for `MNIST`:

```
import caffe
caffe.set_mode_cpu()
import numpy as np

solver = caffe.SGDSolver('solver.prototxt')
solver.net.copy_from('iter_18000.caffemodel')

solver.net.forward()
solver.net.backward()

# the computed derivatives of ip3
# shape of ip3: (10, 300)
computed = np.dot(np.transpose(solver.net.blobs['ip3'].diff),
                               solver.net.blobs['ip2'].data)
# actual derivatives of ip3
actual = solver.net.params['ip3'][0].diff
print np.count_nonzero(computed - actual)
```

The result is 2260. Can someone explain it? many thx.

Comment: Why are you comparing using `count_nonzero()`? Have you tried [`np.allclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)?

Comment: That returns `False`. I also try to print the exact difference between them, and find significant difference.

Comment: how significant?

Comment: When the batchsize is small (like 1), there are many zero columns in `computed - actual`, but if the batchsize get larger, the number of zero columns will become less

Comment: As a supplement, the shape of weight in ip3 is (10, 300). In the case of batchsize = 1, `np.count_nonzero(computed - actual) = 1280`, when batchsize = 100, `np.count_nonzero(computed - actual) = 3000`.

Comment: And this is one typical column `2.23378e-06 0.000368641 -0.00010431 -0.000253077 -1.43023e-05 2.69469e-05 1.28158e-05 -2.33006e-05 -1.01745e-05 -1.00397e-06`

Answer (score 1):

Has been solved! `the computed derivatives of ip3` should be `np.dot(np.transpose(solver.net.blobs['ip3'].diff), solver.net.blobs['relu2'].data)`, that is, in my example, relu is an extra layer.